# How do register an emojii domain?

Tags: domain-registration

I am trying to register an emojii domain, like [Panic did](http://www.panic.com/blog/2011/07/the-worlds-first-emoji-domain/), but I can't seem to get the registrar to recognize the Unicode version of the emojii. Panic's domain is: http://xn--di8h.la/. I was trying to register with both [Hover](http://hover.com) and [iwantmyname](http://iwantmyname.com/) (which was recommended by Panic) and neither of them will allow me to register a domain with `xn--...` characters.

Comment: Did you ask the registrars? Not to bounce you, but the problem is obviously on their end. This question leans a little more toward "potential bug" and so they'd be the best source for a definitive answer. (Then come back and share what they tell you.) For what it's worth, iwantmyname seems to recognize Panic's domain just fine on a domain search, so the problem might be something more specific.

Comment: @Su' I tried the domain that I wanted and searching iwantmyname didn't work...maybe I should talk to them. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Panic blog says only .tk supports emoji domains. Did you try a .tk?

Comment: To our knowledge, only the `.tk` and `.ws` registries currently support emoji domain registration. Will post more here as we learn more.

Answer (score 4):

I just registered a few of these yesterday.

Use http://domai.nr first and type in your emoji icon with the TLD of '.tk'. It will then try to find it, say it is possibly available, then click the iwantmyname link below. It will take you to iwantmyname with the domain pre-populated along with the unicode for it and will allow you to finish the process.

However, I find that many of them are no longer available. So even though domai.nr will say it is possibly available, only iwantmyname will actually tell you.